# Ternary operator: bad or good practice?

Tags: ternary-operator

I'm looking for reasons to use/not to use it and for original ideas (in their use and to replace them).

---

Duplicate:

- [To Ternary Or Not To Ternary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160218/to-ternary-or-not-to-ternary)

Related (but does not address the question being asked):

- [Which coding style you use for ternary operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243217/which-coding-style-you-use-for-ternary-operator)

Comment: what next? usefulness of if statement?

Comment: Sure it is, just replace Ternary with whatever.

Comment: @SilentGhost and Samuel: I don't agree. Nobody really consideres if/then/else a bad practice while very often I hear people discouraging the use of ternary operator.

Comment: All coding practices can be abused. From conditional operators. to ifs, to loops, and gotos.

Comment: People will argue about anything, given the chance. I've heard arguments against the use of if/else, switch, while, return... Thing is, there are folks who will take any possible scenario where problems could result as evidence that the associated construct must be abandoned.

Comment: @Samuel: Please note the conventions for marking duplicates. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610728/how-to-handle-duplicate-questions

Comment: @the post closers: I was waiting for my reply, that is "tell me a way to replace it". If you read Wikipedia, there's a link to a Python workaround, for example. I was looking for similar ideas but you decided to close this question.

Comment: @vyger: We linked to a duplicate, which has a lot of answers.

Comment: @Bill: but you haven't neither given the time to reply... and I only partially see the "duplicate"... anyway, the Q/A website is yours...

Comment: @vyger: There are two edits to your question.  One giving a link to a duplicate and one giving a link to a related question.  Up in the body of the question.

Comment: @vyger: If your question gets closed as duplicate there *should* always be a link to the original question, either in the comments or as an edit to the question.  It's only common courtesy for us to make sure you know where to go to get your answer.

Comment: @Bill: none of them is what I was looking for.

Comment: @vyger the first link should give you what you are after (there are some examples of ?: and ways around it).  The second link is useless to answering your question however.  Can you say why the first link doesn't help?

Comment: @vyger: if you read the linked questions, you'll find what you're asking, and more. Not everyone agrees with your premise, and if/else is a pretty obvious replacement for those that do.

Answer (score 65):

For the sake of readability, I only use a ternary if it fits into one 80-char line.

Comment: Or maybe even a 40-char line

Answer (score 11):

The conditional ternary operator can definitely be overused, and some find it quite unreadable. However, I find that it can be very clean in most situations that a boolean expression is expected, provided that its intent is clear. If the intent is *not* clear, it is best to use a temporary variable with a clear name whose value is assigned using an if-statement, or to use a function with a good name that returns the expected value.

Answer (score 11):

Good for *short tags* in templating languages like PHP, e.g.:

```php
<input type='radio' name='gender' value='m' <?= ($gender == 'm') ? "checked" : "" ?>>Male
<input type='radio' name='gender' value='f' <?= ($gender == 'f') ? "checked" : "" ?>>Female
```

Good for *switches* in JavaScript / jQuery:

```js
let el = $("#something");
$(el).is(':visible') ? $(el).hide("normal") : $(el).fadeIn("normal");
```

Good for *assignments*, especially where a particular variable name can take different types:

```php
$var = ($foo->isFoo()) ? 'Success!' : false;
```

Answer (score 5):

It's something like the `for` loop. Makes sense for what it's made for but when you try to stick more stuff in it, it becomes unreadable.

Answer (score -1):

Which ternary operator are you talking about?

A *ternary operator* is any operator that takes three arguments.

If you're talking about the `? :` operator, this is called the *conditional operator*. I can't live without it anymore, personally. `If` - `else` statements look so messy to me, especially when doing a conditional assignment.

Some complain that it looks messy, but it is still possible (especially if using Visual Studio or another intelligent-formatting IDE) to make things easily readable, and you should be commenting all your conditionals anyway.

Comment: It's usually called the ternary operator because it's the only operator that takes three arguments.

Comment: I'm talking about ? : operator (I always called it ternary operator: am I wrong?)

Comment: +1 for accuracy. Yes, it's called the conditional operator. It happens to be *a* ternary operator, but that only describes the number of operands, not its purpose/behaviour. If the C# team every introduces another ternary operator, people are really going to have to learn the right name...

Comment: Commenting ALL your conditionals?  Really?

Comment: Yes, commenting all your conditionals. It is one thing to read through one logical flow of a method and find out what it does, but ascertaining WHY something happens is much harder, and that question comes up much more with conditionals.

Comment: Many years ago, I used to comment each of my if statements.  I felt it made the code easier to read... and it did to some extent.  I changed my thinking, when I found a better way.  _Clean Code_ book by Robert C Martin essentially says name every method, variable name very clearly, and use small functions.  When applying this, my need for comments was reduced and I feel my code is even more readable!