# Ruby: nested regular expressions and string replace

Tags: ruby, coderay

I'm using CodeRay for syntax highlighting, but I'm having trouble with this regular expression. The text will look like this:

```
<pre><code>:::ruby
def say_hello
  puts 'hello!'
end
</code></pre>
```

This part: `:::ruby` will tell CodeRay which language the code block should be interpreted as (but it needs to be optional). So here's what I have so far:

```
def coderay(text)
  text.gsub(/\<pre\>\<code\>(.+?)\<\/code\>\<\/pre\>/m) do
    CodeRay.scan($2, $3).div()
  end
end
```

`$2` contains the code that I'm formatting (including the line that says which language to format it in), but I need to extract that first line so I can pass it as the second parameter to `scan()` or pass it a default parameter if that language line wasn't found. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you using Ruby 1.8 or 1.9?

Comment: either one. does it make a difference?

Comment: REs in Ruby 1.9 support named groups. Also, do you simply want Ruby to be the default language, or do you want a more complex way of figuring out what language to interpret the code as?

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby 1.9, using named groups:

```
default_lang=:ruby

def coderay(text)
  text.gsub(%r!<pre><code>(?::{3}(?<lang>\w+)\s+)?(?<code>.+?)</code></pre>!m) do
    if $~[:lang].nil?
      lang=default_lang
    else
      lang = $~[:lang].intern
    end
    CodeRay.scan($~[:code], lang).div()
  end
end
```

`default_lang` could also be a class or object variable rather than a local, depending on the context of `coderay`.

Same, but using an inline expression to handle the optional language:

```
default_lang=:ruby

def coderay(text)
  text.gsub(%r!<pre><code>(?::{3}(?<lang>\w+)\s+)?(?<code>.+?)</code></pre>!m) do
    CodeRay.scan($~[:code], $~[:lang].nil? ? default_lang : $~[:lang].intern).div()
  end
end
```

The second option is a little messier, hence you [might want to avoid it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694814/ternary-operator-bad-or-best-practice).

It turns out named groups in a non-matching optional group are still counted in Ruby, so handling unmatched numbered groups isn't any different from unmatched named groups, unlike what I first thought. You can thus replace the named group references with positional references in the above and it should work the same.

```
default_lang=:ruby

def coderay(text)
  text.gsub(%r!<pre><code>(?::{3}(?<lang>\w+)\s+)?(?<code>.+?)</code></pre>!m) do
    CodeRay.scan($2, $1.nil? ? default_lang : $1.intern).div()
  end
end

def coderay(text)
  text.gsub(%r!<pre><code>(?::{3}(?<lang>\w+)\s+)?(?<code>.+?)</code></pre>!m) do
    if $1.nil?
      lang=default_lang
    else
      lang = $1.intern
    end
    CodeRay.scan($2, lang).div()
  end
end
```

Comment: What would the 1.8 syntax look like?