# Process incoming serial stream without LF CR

Tags: c, stream, raspberry-pi, serial-port, wiringpi

The code below processes incoming RS232 serial data 1 character at a time and works fine.

However the incoming serial feed in my use case does not contain any CR or LF characters which make further delimiting/processing to a piped program difficult.
The end delimiter is always a ! exclamation character instead of a CR or LF. e.g.   123456!abcdef!qwerty!

Is there a way to modify the code below to substitute the ! character to a CR (carriage return)? For example, is the incoming string is 123456abcdef! then the program should replace the ! with a CR so it outputs 123456abcdef<carriage return>

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <wiringSerial.h>

int main ()

  for (;;)
  {
    putchar (serialGetchar (fd)) ;
    fflush (stdout) ;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in the same single char basis as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <wiringSerial.h>

int main ()

  for (;;)
  {
    char c = serialGetchar (fd);
    putchar (c == '!' ? '\r' : c) ;
    fflush (stdout) ;
  }
}
```

Normally it is used new line with carriage return, in that case would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <wiringSerial.h>

int main ()

  for (;;)
  {
    char c = serialGetchar (fd);
    if (c == '!')
    {
        putchar ('\r') ;
        putchar ('\n') ;
    }
    else
    {
        putchar (c) ;
    }
    fflush (stdout) ;
  }
}
```

Comment: `c == '!' ? '\r' : c` introduces implicit promotion to `int`, which isn't desired. Use an `if` statement to avoid this (and make the code easier to read at the same time).

Comment: 3 on-line sources indicate `serialGetchar()` returns `int`.  `putchar()` tales an `int`.  Recommend `int c = serialGetchar (fd);`.

Comment: thanks so much to everyone for your answers. the problem is solved.

Comment: `putchar()` nominally takes an `int` but only the low-end byte is used: the `int` is cast to an `unsigned char`. I would assume `serialGetchar()` does the opposite: returns an `unsigned char` cast to an `int`. Similarly, the statement `c == '!' ? '\r' : c` implicitly promotes everything to `int` because character literals are `int`s in c, but this isn't actually a problem because the promotion consistently discards everything but the low-end byte. It's not as if 1 in 256 times the cast turns `0xff` into `0x00` due to integer overflow. The cast behaves absolutely predictably.

Comment: @Lundin any valid argument passed to `putchar()` is promoted to `int`. I completely fail to see why this "isn't desired".

Answer (score 1):

```
char c = serialGetchar (fd)) ;
c = (c == '!') ? '\r' : c ;
putchar (c) ;
```

Or, put another way,

```
char c = serialGetchar (fd)) ;
if (c == '!') c = '\r' ;
putchar (c) ;
```

Comment: The second version is better since it is easier to read and doesn't contain any implicit promotion weirdness. Thanks to implicit promotion, version 1) tries to store an `int` inside a `char` which isn't really helpful.

Comment: Simple ternaries aren't difficult to read...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/160295/4024569
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694814/ternary-operator-bad-or-good-practice

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the whole code with

```
for(;;)
{
  char c = serialGetchar (fd);
  if(c == '!')
  {
    putchar('\n');
  }
  else
  {
    putchar(c);
    fflush (stdout);
  }
}
```

It isn't necessary to flush stdout after writing a `'\n'` to it - doing this will trigger a flush automatically. So as a minor optimization, this code doesn't flush stdout twice upon finding a `'!'`.

Comment: *It isn't necessary to flush stdout after writing a `'\n'`...*  To be (overly?) pedantic, that's only true if the stream is in line-buffer mode.

Comment: To that minor point [... rules of automatic flushing stdout buffer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39536212/2410359)