# How to use ternary operator instead of if-else in PHP

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I’m trying to shorten my code using the ternary operator.

This is my original code:

```
if ($type = "recent") {
    $OrderType = "sid DESC";
} elseif ($type = "pop") {
    $OrderType = "counter DESC";
} else {
    $OrderType = "RAND()";
}
```

How can I use the ternary operator in my code instead of `if`s/`else`s?

```
$OrderType = ($type = "recent") ? "sid DESC" : "counter DESC" ;
```

This is the code I tried, but have no idea how to add an “`elseif` part” to it.

Comment: you don't need to change your code, it's perfectly readable and fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which coding style you use for ternary operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243217/which-coding-style-you-use-for-ternary-operator)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is called the **ternary operator** ;-)

You could use two of those :

```
$OrderType = ($type == 'recent' ? 'sid DESC' : ($type == 'pop' ? 'counter DESC' : 'RAND()'))
```

This can be read as :

- if `$type` is `'recent'`
- then use `'sid DESC'`
- else

  - if `$type` is `'pop'`
  - then use `'counter DESC'`
  - else use `'RAND()'`

A couple of notes :

- **You must use `==` or `===` ; and not `=`**

  - The first two ones are [comparison operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)
  - The last one is the [assignment operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php)
- It's best to use `()`, to make things easier to read

  - And you shouldn't use too many ternary operators like that : it makes code a bit hard to understand, i think

And, as a reference about the ternary operator, quoting the [**Operators** section of the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php) :

> The third group is the ternary
>   operator: `?:`. 
> It should be used
>   to select between two expressions
>   depending on a third one, rather than
>   to select two sentences or paths of
>   execution. 
> Surrounding ternary
>   expressions with parentheses is a very
>   good idea.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using a case statement instead.  it makes it a little more readable but more maintainable for when you want to add extra options

```
switch ($type)
{
case "recent":
  $OrderType =  "sid DESC"; 
  break;
case "pop":
  $OrderType =  "counter DESC"; 
  break;
default:
   $OrderType =  "RAND()"; 
}
```

Comment: The question is about ternary operators, but I agree, in this case, switch makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Ah well, the question is to "shorten or better" - less lines doesnt always == better; I like ternary operators but sometimes they just arent the right thing to use.