# PHP into html <option...> code

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to put this string that work fine as php:

```
if ($sortvalue == $sort[3]) { echo 'selected=' ;}
```

into this code:

```
echo '<select onchange="this.form.submit();" name="sort">
<option value="'.$sort[3].'" HERE_THE_PHP_CODE>Price</option>
[..]
</select>';
```

I tried a lot of syntax but I got always a blank page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use ternary operator instead of if-else in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705109/how-to-use-ternary-operator-instead-of-if-else-in-php)

Comment: check your error log or add in the top  `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the code clean you should use the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary). It will allow you to do an if statement inside your echo.

```
echo '<select onchange="this.form.submit();" name="sort">
<option value="'.$sort[3].'" ' . ($sort[3] == $sortvalue ? 'selected' : '') . '>Price</option>
[..]
</select>';
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked! How is it possible just not to insert the "if" condition and make it works anyway??? I would never find this solution by myself..

Comment: @Rain_xx you are using the if condition by using the ternary operator, for more information, please check the link provided by Marwelln

Answer (score 2):

```
$selected = '';

if ($sortvalue == $sort[3]) { $selected = 'selected'; }

echo '<select onchange="this.form.submit();" name="sort">
<option value="'.$sort[3].'" $selected>Price</option>
</select>';
```

This should do what you want. (the reply by Osama has an error in the if statement)