# PHP Alternative Syntax

Tags: php

```
<?php

require_once 'app/init.php';

$itemsQuery=$db->prepare("
    SELECT id, name, done
    FROM items
    WHERE user=:user 
    ");

$itemsQuery->execute([
    'user'=>$_SESSION['user_id']
]);

$items=$itemsQuery->rowCount() ? $itemsQuery : [];
```

Hello, I was watching a tutorial on youtube and I have problems understanding      " ? " and " : " in the last line of the code shown.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It's called a ternary operator

Comment: And to add to @j08691 you can read more about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705109/how-to-use-ternary-operator-instead-of-if-else-in-php

Comment: [More information here](https://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples)