# Can I customize the indentation of ternary operators in emacs' cperl-mode?

Tags: perl, emacs, indentation, ternary-operator, cperl-mode

In emacs cperl-mode, ternary operators are not treated specially. If you break them over multiple lines, cperl-mode simply indents each line the same way it indents any continued statement, like this:

```
$result = ($foo == $bar)  ? 'result1' :
    ($foo == $baz)  ? 'result2' :
        ($foo == $qux)  ? 'result3' :
            ($foo == $quux) ? 'result4' : 
                'fail_result';
```

This is not very readable. Is there some way that I can convince cperl-mode indent like this?

```
$result = ($foo == $bar)  ? 'result1' :
          ($foo == $baz)  ? 'result2' :
          ($foo == $qux)  ? 'result3' :
          ($foo == $quux) ? 'result4' : 
                            'fail_result';
```

By the way, code example from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243217/which-coding-style-you-use-for-ternary-operator).

#### EDIT

There seems to be a bug in cperl-mode's indentation of ternary operators. Take the following example, which was indented using Emacs 23.1.1, cperl-mode version 5.23:

```
my $result = ($foo == $bar)  ? 'result1' :
  ($foo == $baz)  ? 'result2' :
  ($foo == $qux)  ? 'result3' :
  ($foo == $quux) ? 'result4' :
  'fail_result';

{
  my $result = ($foo == $bar)  ? 'result1' :
    ($foo == $baz)  ? 'result2' :
      ($foo == $qux)  ? 'result3' :
        ($foo == $quux) ? 'result4' :
          'fail_result';
}
```

Notice that outside any braces, I basically get the indentation I want. But inside braces, the ternary operator is indented badly. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: +1 good question, I've been wondering about this myself.

Comment: To be clear, I'd like to be able to do this with emacs's built-in indentation facilities, so that using TAB does the right thing. But failing that, other solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of cperl-mode and Emacs are you using?  In GNU Emacs 23.1, `cperl-version` 5.23, with no init file, I get:

```
$result = ($foo == $bar)  ? 'result1' :
  ($foo == $baz)  ? 'result2' :
  ($foo == $qux)  ? 'result3' :
  ($foo == $quux) ? 'result4' :
  fail_result;
```

If I want them to line up under the first, I'd add an extra set of parens:

```
$result = (($foo == $bar)  ? 'result1' :
           ($foo == $baz)  ? 'result2' :
           ($foo == $qux)  ? 'result3' :
           ($foo == $quux) ? 'result4' :
           fail_result);
```

I'm pretty sure that achieving your requested indentation (with `fail_result` lining up with the `'result'` strings) would require some non-trivial changes to cperl-mode's indentation engine.  You're welcome to try it, though. :-)

Comment: Hmm. I think I've found a bug in cperl-mode's indentation. I'll edit my question with details.

Comment: Wait a minute, wouldn't an extra set of parents force list context? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886751/how-can-i-tell-if-a-set-of-parens-in-perl-code-will-act-as-grouping-parens-or-for

Comment: @Ryan Thompson: No.  To get list context, you'd have to put the parens around `$result`, not around the expression you're assigning to `$result`.

Comment: I realize that the assignment would happen in scalar context, but an extra pair of parens could still end up creating a one-element list and thereby assigning the number 1 to `$result`.

Comment: @Ryan Thompson: No. Parens on the right-hand side of an assignment operator do not create list context. `$x = ((((func))));` is exactly equivalent to `$x = func;`.  To get list context, you put the parens to the left of the assignment: `($x) = func;` calls `func` in list context.

Comment: Grr. This solution isn't compatible with setting `cperl-indent-parens-as-block`, which I like.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about auto-indentation in Cperl-mode but `M-1 M-S-| perltidy` (if you have [Perl::Tidy](http://search.cpan.org/~shancock/Perl-Tidy-20090616/) installed) will tidy a marked region (including ternary statements) nicely. By default it won't look precisely like your example but I believe you can customise it to do what you want in its .perltidyrc.

I didn't figure this out myself btw - I read it somewhere - I thought PBP but I've just checked & it doesn't seem to be that, but anyway I use it all the time & find it very useful.

Edit: It was on the [cperl page in the emacs wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CPerlMode)