# inline elseif in PHP

Tags: php

Is there a way to have an inline if statement in PHP which also includes a elseif?

I would assume the logic would go something like this:

```
$unparsedCalculation = ($calculation > 0) ? "<span style=\"color: #9FE076;\">".$calculation : ($calculation < 0) ? "<span style=\"color: #FF736A;\">".$calculation : $calculation;
```

Comment: That's incredibly hard to read. It will be a maintenance nightmare in the future.

Comment: Did you try the code you posted? Did it work? If not, what error/wrong behavior did you observe?

Comment: Touche, Radu - I agree. This is just the first elseif statement I could readily find in my code.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`elseif` is nothing more than `else if`, so, practically, there *is* no `elseif`, it's just a convenience. The same convenience is not provided for the ternary operator, because the ternary operator is meant to be used for very short logic.

```
if ($a) { ... } elseif ($b) { ... } else { ... }
```

is identical to

```
if ($a) { ... } else { if ($b) { ... } else { ... } }
```

Therefore, the ternary equivalent is

```
$a ? ( ... ) : ( $b ? ( ... ) : ( ... ) )
```

Comment: While you are correct that nested ternary statements should be enclosed in parentheses, it has nothing to do with if...else if.  Ternary in PHP is left-associative (it is evaluated from left to right). http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php

Answer (score 3):

you can use nested Ternary Operator

```
      (IF ? THEN : ELSE) 
      (IF ? THEN : ELSE(IF ? THEN : ELSE(IF ? THEN : ELSE))
```

for better readability coding standard can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243217/which-coding-style-you-use-for-ternary-operator)

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap some of that in parenthesis for order of operation issues, but sure, you could do that.  While there is no "elseif" for ternary operators, it's effectively the same thing

`if (condition) ? (true) : (false> if (condition) ? (true) : (false));`

Though you really shouldn't code like this...it's confusing from a readability perspective.  Nobody is going to look at that and be "sweet, ninja!" they will say "ugh, wtf"

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
(($condition_1) ? "output_1" : (($condition_2) ?  "output_2" : "output_3"));
```

In your case it will be:

```
$unparsedCalculation = (($calculation > 0) ? "<span style=\"color: #9FE076;\">".$calculation : (($calculation < 0) ?  "<span style=\"color: #FF736A;\">".$calculation : $calculation));
```