# How to properly nest ternary operators?

Tags: php, echo, ternary-operator

I know that it is possible to nest ternary operators, and I want to use them in this case to save time (at least in the future).

I have a variable that will hold one of four values:

- "admin"
- "edit"
- "wadmin"
- "wuser"

Each of these is used to determine necessary password lengths based on the user type, 16, 12, 8, and 8, respectively.

I want PHP to echo each of those numbers based on the contents of the variable, in this case named `$match`

What I have so far is this:

```
echo $match == "admin" ? "16" : $match == "edit" ? "12" : "8";
```

But this always echoes 12. How can I rewrite this to properly echo "16", "12", or "8"?

Comment: PHP's ternary operator is broken.

Comment: @elclanrs So you're saying this *should* work, even though it doesn't?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which coding style you use for ternary operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243217/which-coding-style-you-use-for-ternary-operator)

Comment: "possible to nest ternary operators" — Possible, but not a good idea, it just makes code hard to read — "and I want to use them in this case to save time" — Ternary operators take more time to plan then simple if statements (so don't save development time) and don't run any faster than an if statement (so don't save any runtime).

Comment: I suppose so, but they were still a part of programming I never understood before, and now I do! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick.

enclose the `false` condition in brackets / parentheses

```
echo ($match == 'admin') ? '16' : (($match == 'edit') ? '12' : '8');
```

or

```
echo $match == 'admin' ? '16' : ($match == 'edit' ? '12' : '8');
```

Comment: Yay! That makes sense too. Dang parentheses! 8 min til I can accept.

Comment: This is PHP specific because unlike most other languages PHP reads ternary operator left-to-right. It's not worth even doing this IMO, I'd use a `switch` or `elseif`.

Answer (score 4):

Although it doesn't directly answer the question, you could avoid the nested-ternary entirely:

```
<?php
$minlen = array(
    "admin" => 16,
    "edit" => 12,
    "wadmin" => 8,
    "wuser" => 8,
);

// Example usage
$match = "admin";
echo $minlen[$match];
?>
```

Comment: This is way better than the original approach with ternary operators. It avoids having to fiddle with complicated code, and allows for very easy changing or adding of the values.

Answer (score 0):

Use nested, i hope help you. You can extend forever ;)

```
echo $match == "admin" ? "16" : ($match == "edit" ? "12" : ($match == "wadmin" ? "8" : ($match == "wuser" ? "4" : "NONE")));
```

Answer (score 0):

use parantheses:
`echo $match == "admin" ? "16" : ($match == "edit" ? "12" : "8");`