# Can i use multiple line in ternary operator

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I want to use the if else statement in the ternary operator

```
     if (open) {
         setOpen(false)
     } else {
         setOpen(true)
         navigator.clipboard.writeText(link)
     }
```

There is no problem in "if" I cant figuring out how to convert else to ternary. Like something the code below:

```
open ? setOpen(false) : setOpen(true) ; navigator.clipboard.writeText(link)
```

Something like this or is there another method to do the job?

Comment: Ternary is for one-liners. Dont overthink it. 
If it is not a one-liner just write good old if-else.

Comment: Don't cram multiple lines onto one. What possible reason would you have for doing this? Lines cost nothing. You're just making taking clear, obvious code and making it brittle and prone to bugs.

Comment: [Similar discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/243217/1357094) (somewhat language-agnostic)

Answer (score 5):

Don't.

You're trying to use the ternary conditional operator for the wrong reason.  It is **not** a drop-in replacement for any `if` block.

The ternary conditional operator is an *expression*.  It resolves to a value, which can be used elsewhere.  For example:

```
let x = someCondition ? 1 : 0;
```

The expression resolves to a value, either `1` or `0`, and that value is used in an assignment statement.

The code you're showing is *not an expression*.  What you have is a series of *statements*, conditionally executed based on some value.  An `if` block is a structure for conditionally executing statements.

The code you have now is correct.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. it is possible (although not a best practice and not recommended)

they way to to it is by:

1. Put everything inside parenthesis
2. Seperate each statement with comma (",")

e.g:

```
condition ? statement1 : ( statement2, statement3, statement4 )
```

Try this snippet:

```js
let a = 1;
let b = 1;
a == b ?
(console.log("they"),console.log("are"), console.log("equal")) :
(console.log("they're"), console.log("not equal"));
```

Answer (score 1):

this might do the trick

```js
true ? (() => { 
      console.log(1);
      console.log(2);
      console.log(3);
    })() : false
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to write multiple statements in ternary `if` `else` cases:

The format is:

`condition ? codeLine1 : ( codeLine2 , codeLine3 )`

Which makes your statement as:

```
open ? setOpen(false) : (setOpen(true), navigator.clipboard.writeText(link));
```

Combine multiple statements in parenthesis separated by commas in between each line.

That being said it's recommended to use old fashioned way of if-else statement if multiple statements are involved.

Please select answer if it helps and let me know if any questions.

Comment: This does not work anymore, you can try this syntax instead `condition ? codeLine1 : ( codeLine2) && (codeLine3 )`